# Is there any way to use Snippets for Google Apps Script like VSCode for snippets.json?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ecmascript-5

I found this useful article.

https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/blob/master/sheets/api/spreadsheet_snippets.gs

But currently I just copy and paste these function.
Is there any way to use these snippets like saving somewhere and calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way. If you want to access one of your Spreadsheets from a code running  on VScode, then use the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) with the programming language of your preference. Here I leave you some quickstart from different languajes:

- [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)
- [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs)
- [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [clasp](/questions/tagged/clasp) to push code from vscode. In [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) you can use any of the vanilla js snippets or use your own snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of this approach, but you could put Grant's Snippet module into its own [Apps Script library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries). Then you could import the library as needed from project to project.

Comment: Thank you, and I realized that developing on browser must be mistake as you said. But This is good knowledg. Thank you very much.